# why my python program is printing none on next line,even after using return

Tags: python-3.x

```
def rotatelist(l,k):
    n=len(l)
    if k<0:
        return(print(l))
    k=k%n
    b=[0]*n
    for i in range(0,n):
       b[(i+k)%n]=l[i]
    return(print(b))
```

this my code i have written to rotate list, to stop it printing None on next line after printing list i have used return but it is still printing None on next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rotatelist(l, k):
    n = len(l)
    if k < 0:
        return(l)
    k = k % n
    b = [0] * n
    for i in range(0, n):
       b[(i + k) % n] = l[i]
    return(b)

a = [1, 2, 3]
print(rotatelist(a, 2))
```

When invoking print() always returns None, that is, you were printing the value and returning None, and then printing None

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning values b or l, but instead what ever the print(b) and print(l) functions are returning (which is None). Try returning only the values:

```
def rotatelist(l, k):
    n = len(l)
    if k < 0:
        return l
    k = k % n
    b = [0]*n
    for i in range(0, n):
        b[(i+k) % n] = l[i]
    return b

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print("start testing")
new_list = rotatelist(a, 3)
print("print result")
print(new_list)
print("testing over")
```

which gives output:

```
start testing
print result
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
testing over
```